# firebase_messaging onResume and onLaunch not working in version 6.0.16

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I faced this issue particularly on the iOS platform that I cannot get a push notification using a firebase_messaging plugin with version **6.0.16**.

Answer (score 0):

This strange issue is happening in version **6.0.16**. When I downgrade the plugin version in my pubspec.yaml with **6.0.12**, notifications start working.

Comment: Could you please elaborate and add some code, I'm using 6.0.16 in one of my projects & I have no issues with onResume or OnLaunch methods.

Comment: I was not getting any push notification in iOS device in background mode and in kill state. That's why I downgrade the plugin and started getting notifications.